# Fitting data to a line, if the data has tolerances

Tags: approximation, data-analysis

I need to fit data to a line.
This data also includes tolerances.

**Now, I was wondering, if there exists a method, to account for those tolerances?**

For instance, a data point with a lot of tolerances should not be given the same weight as a data point with small tolerances.

Here is a sample of my data:

x| Data-point (y) | +/- tolerance

1| 120.984 | 0.426248

2| 132.194  | 0.418291

3| 130.413  | 1.260100

4| 127.687  | 0.414457

5| 125.710  | 0.410716

6| 128.188  | 1.431200

Comment: Are there $x$ values? Do they have uncertainty too?

Comment: OK, so there are $x$ values but they are certain. Then yes, it can be done. Put the standard deviations into a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$, and make $A$ have a column of $1$s and a column of $x$ values. Then you want to choose $x$ to minimize $\| \Sigma^{-1} (Ap-y) \|^2$, where $p=\begin{bmatrix} b \\ m \end{bmatrix}$ contains the y-intercept and slope of your line. (I think that exponent should be $-1$, but I haven't done the derivation recently...)

Comment: @lan Thanks a lot ! Some questions to clarify:

Comment: I can write a little more about how to compute the optimal $p$, but it would be helpful to know how much detail I need to go into. Do you know what an inner product is? Do you know what an adjoint is? Do you know how to compute an adjoint of a matrix in an inner product other than the Euclidean one?

Comment: @lan Thank you very much. I am afraid, but I am quiet new to the subject. I now what an inner product is. I would have to look up what an  Adjoint is. How is your method called ? Can the tolerance be equal to the standard deviation ... or do I need to normalize ? ...and what do you mean by the exponent "should be -1" ?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with standard deviations as its diagonal entries (hence why I chose that symbol for it). $A$ is basically just a matrix that says "I'm trying to fit to a line and the $x$ values are these". $y$ is the vector of $y$ values. When I said "the exponent should be $-1$ I meant that it should be $\Sigma^{-1}$ in the objective function and not $\Sigma^{-2}$ or something like that, but I'm not 100% certain because I haven't done weighted least squares (which is what this is called) recently.

Comment: Anyway, that tells me what to tell you. Since $\| \Sigma^{-1}(Ap-y) \|^2 = \langle Ap-y,Ap-y \rangle_{\Sigma^{-2}}$ where $\langle x,z \rangle_{\Sigma^{-2}} = x^T \Sigma^{-2} y$, this minimization problem boils down to solving the normal equations in this "biased" inner product. That is, you want to solve $A^* A p = A^* y$ where $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$ relative to $\langle x,z \rangle_{\Sigma^{-2}}$. The idea here is just that the $y$ values with lower standard deviations are counted more.

Comment: @lan Thank you!! :) I will try to understand your method better and post a comment, if I do struggle. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly just hashing out some details from the comments section above.

We are given with a model matrix $A$ (which in this case has a column of $1$s and a column of $x$ values), and a vector of true $y$ values $y$. If we choose a parameter vector $p$ (in this case containing an intercept and a slope), we have the predicted $y$ values $\hat{y}=Ap$. In standard least squares we try to minimize $\| \hat{y}-y \|^2$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm.

In weighted least squares, we weigh some entries more and others less. Given standard deviations $\sigma_i$ for the measured $y_i$, it makes sense to think of $(\hat{y}-y)_i$ in units of $\sigma_i$. We can achieve that by making a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ with diagonal entries $\sigma_i$ and then trying to minimize $\| \Sigma^{-1}(Ap-y) \|^2$. We'll rewrite this as $\langle Ap-y,Ap-y \rangle$ where $\langle x,y \rangle$ is defined to be $(x,\Sigma^{-2}y)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Euclidean inner product.

Then we require the solution $p^*$ to be such that $Ap^*-y$ is orthogonal to all vectors of the form $Ap$ in our weighted inner product. That is $\langle Ap,Ap^*-y \rangle = 0$ or $p^T A^T \Sigma^{-2}(Ap^*-y)=0$ for every $p$. This occurs if and only if $A^T \Sigma^{-2}(Ap^*-y)=0$ (just check it with $p$ equal to the standard basis vectors). Thus the normal equations in the end read

$$A^T \Sigma^{-2} A p^* = A^T \Sigma^{-2} y.$$